# Getting distance in django with out a geoDjango backend (PostGIS, etc...)

Tags: python, django, gis, geodjango, geos

I don't want to go through the pain of installing PostGIS so can I get places ordered by distance from an origin using `django.contrib.gis`?

models.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lat = models.FloatField()
    lng = models.FloatField()

    def point(self):
        return Point(self.lat,self.lng)
```

views.py

```
origin = Point(lookup_lat,lookup_lng)
places = Place.objects.filter(point__distance_lte=(origin, D(mi=10))).distance(origin).order_by('distance')[:20]
```

I've tried this but I get `Cannot resolve keyword 'point' into field.`

Answer (score 0):

Installing the package `libgeos-dev` should solve this error in some of the cases.

Comment: even just a `Place.objects.filter(point__distance_lte=(origin, D(mi=10)))` wont work :(. I don't think it likes `point` as a function

Comment: same as the one in the question

Comment: ended up using `__gt` & `__lt` on the lat,lng in my db instead (i.e. getting all the locations inside a box)